# two level add more filed in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make Create Quiz Page. there should be dynamically inputs on-page. there is no defined number of questions and a number of answers to each question. for add question, I'm using bootstrap accordion and it works. after click add question it appends new accordion and inputs inside. but in a second-level load more after button click, nothing happens. also, I want dynamically add answers. I'm using same logic. after #question click I creating HTML element ad trying to append inside answersAccordion.
jQuery click event not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var next = 0;
    $("#add-more").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let _html = '';

        _html+='<div class="card">';
            _html+='<div class="card-header" id="heading'+next+'">';
                _html+='<h5 class="mb-0">';
                    _html+='<button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse'+next+'" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse'+next+'">';
                        _html+='Quiz question: '+next;
                    _html+='</button>'
                _html+='</h5>';
            _html+='</div>';
            _html+='<div id="collapse'+next+'" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading'+next+'" data-parent="#accordion">';
                _html+='<div class="card-body">';
                    _html+='<input form="myform" type="text" name="questions[][question]">'
                    _html+='<input form="myform" type="file" name="questions[][image]">'
                    _html+='<div class="col-md-3">';
                        _html+='<button id="question" name="add-question" class="btn btn-primary">Add Question</button>'
                        _html+='<div id="answersAccordion">';

                        _html+='</div>';
                    _html+='</div>';
                _html+='</div>'
            _html+='</div>'
        _html+='</div>'

        $('#accordion').append(_html);
        next+=1;
    });

    $("#question").click(function(e){
        console.log(12121)
        let _html = '';
        _html+='<div class="ml-5">'
            _html+='<input type="text" name="questions[][answers][][title]">';
            _html+='<textarea name="questions[][answers][][description]"></textarea>';
            _html+='<input type="file" name="questions[][answers][][image]" ';
        _html+='</div>'
        $(this).next().append(_html);
        console.log($(e))
    });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <button id="add-more" name="add-more" class="btn btn-primary">Add More</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form id="myform" method="post" action="post.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <button>send</button>
    </form>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-12" >
            <h3> Actions</h3>
            <div id="accordion">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

console.log not working also
in the console, there is no error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is other way to make the code better and cleaner.
I hope it helps.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var next = 0;
    $("#add-more").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let _html = `
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="heading ${next}">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-${next}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-${next}">
                        Quiz question: ${next}
                    </button>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-${next}" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading ${next}" data-parent="#accordion">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <input form="myform" type="text" name="questions[][question]">
                    <input form="myform" type="file" name="questions[][image]">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <button id="question" name="add-question" class="btn btn-primary add-question-${next}">Add Question</button>
                        <div id="answersAccordion">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        `;
        $('#accordion').append(_html);
        $(`.add-question-${next}`).click(function(e){
            let _html = `
            <div class="ml-5">
                <input type="text" name="questions[][answers][][title]">
                <textarea name="questions[][answers][][description]"></textarea>
                <input type="file" name="questions[][answers][][image]" 
            </div>
            `;
            $(this).next().append(_html);
        });
        next+=1;
    });
});
```